# Alternative to NSCollectionView in pre-OSX10.5, Cocotron?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscollectionview

`NSCollectionView` was introduced in OS X 10.5, and is not yet implemented in Cocotron.

I am trying to implement a small app that will allow creating properly packaged data files for an online service, which will then be uploaded by an administrator. More specifically, the user will create a collection of input and output data pairs, by dragging input and output files onto the window.

Currently the idea is that user drags a file, from the filename it's detected if it's the input or output filename (by default, input), and a view with icon and filename for input and output is added to collection view. Then, the second file is dropped on the "other" icon.

[image: NSCollectionViewItem's view]

However, `NSCollectionView` does not appear in pre-10.5, and most of my users don't have Macs so I'll have to provide a Cocotron-built application. Not only that; I still don't fully understand KVC/KVO, and I really should understand everything that my code does. Hence, I need an alternative to `NSCollectionView`.

**What alternative do I have to using `NSCollectionView`?** (Any intuitive solution is appreciated, don't feel limited by the above description of my idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with NSCollectionView, you need to not only understand KVC and KVO, but also [Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/CocoaBindingsRef.html).

There's code for an NSCollectionView clone that works on Tiger [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CollectionViewForTiger).

Comment: Thank you! When I'll go back to this project, I'll check this out and accept the solution.

Comment: I decided that it's more intuitive to use NSTableView and sheets than collection view, but I shall nevertheless accept the answer since it looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

> I still don't fully understand KVC/KVO…

That's what the docs are for:

- [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/)
- [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/)

> What alternative do I have to using NSCollectionView?

Make your own.